# What are the sounds in this GoPro-in-orbit ISS video?

Tags: iss, imaging, sound, robotic-arm

The video description says:

> Published on Apr 15, 2015
>   This footage was taken by U.S. astronaut Terry Virts during a spacewalk on the International Space Station on February 25, 2015. Virts and fellow astronaut Barry “Butch” Wilmore routed a series of cables in preparation for the arrival of two International Docking Adapters later in 2015. Virts also lubricated elements at the latching end of the space station’s Canadarm2 robotic arm while Wilmore prepares the Tranquility module for the relocation of the Permanent Multipurpose Module and the arrival of the Bigelow Expandable Activity Module (BEAM) later this year.

Can anyone identify the source of the sounds recorded by the GoPro?

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19440/12102) describes another GoPro video, and why the recorded sounds transmitted through air became more audible as the air density increased, around 30km altitude. But the current video is from the ISS at 400km. I'm guessing the sounds is transmitted mechanically from something in contact with the camera. Is it related to the astronaut's EVA suit, or the ISS?

Thanks to @BrianTompsett for [linking to](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14327/has-there-ever-been-a-go-pro-satellite#comment37532_14327) this GoPro video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sounds are undoubtedly the microphone simply picking up (via conduction) random vibrations in the camera body due to handling.

Interestingly, the audio track appears to be out of sync from the video -- many of those rustling sounds appear about one or two seconds after the camera is visibly jostled.

Comment: Starting around `01:30`until about `07:00` there is a continuous humming/gurgling sound, like a pump or compressor. It's not a pure tone like an oscillator but slightly noisy in frequency. The frequency is the `E` above `middle-C`, or about 330 Hz. *What is that??*

Comment: I'm hoping this guy's `A 440` is correct https://youtu.be/1ATPBGXTunI I don't have anything else handy, and too lazy to do it in Python.

Comment: That sounds like mechanical noise from the suit -- in that shot, the camera is attached to the crew member's HUT (Hard Upper Torso).  Likely vibration transmitted from the ventilation fan.

Comment: Hello LEE my old friend! (starting at 2:48) also a good view of the rotating experiment antenna mounted on Columbus.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's a great view of the [Rapid Scan Antenna](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/8742/12102), not an [SGANT](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/16570/12102) as you have explained. Who/what is "LEE... (starting at 2:48"?

Comment: LEE is the Latching End Effector, the "business end" of the robot arm.  that's what you see slowly rotating at the left of the frame.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I see - so it connects to something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Power_Data_Grapple_Fixture_on_station.jpg

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is a question on here where I gave more details. Am on bad device now, can't search for it.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14973/what-are-joint-systems-used-for-mounting-manipulators-to-spacecrafts/14989#14989